# What are the prerequisites for ruby-qml?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, qml

I am trying to install [ruby-qml](https://github.com/seanchas116/ruby-qml) on Ubuntu 15.10 (Wily). Apparently some prerequisites are missing:

```
:#> gem install qml
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing qml:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby2.1 extconf.rb
checking for qmake... yes
  >>> building libqmlbind...
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: qml quick
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
ERROR: Failed to build libqmlbind
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby2.1
        --with-qmake
        --without-qmake
        --enable-debug
        --disable-debug
        --enable-clean
        --disable-clean

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/qml-1.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/qml-1.0.2/gem_make.out
```

I already tried to install some of the usual suspects (build-essential bison openssl libreadline5 libreadline-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev vim libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev git-core subversion autoconf xorg-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev), but no luck.

There are no prerequisites mentioned for Linux in the documentation.
**What is missing?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing `libqt5quickparticles5` and `qtdeclarative5-dev` helped to get a step further. Yet, there were plenty more missing packages.

`qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu` has a rather exhaustive list of useful dependencies for qt5 programming. Installing it solved my troubles.

Answer (score 5):

You are most probably missing Qt packages. Evident by following line of error:

> Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: qml quick

Install it using:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5 qtdeclarative5-dev qt5-default
```

Answer (score 2):

I've followed the mentioned answers here, but it didn't work alone. I found another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35022321/967283)

So in my case, I've installed the following packages in order to install ruby-qml successfully.

- libqt5qml5
- libqt5quick5
- qtdeclarative5-dev
- qt5-default
- qtbase5-private-dev

`apt install libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5 qtdeclarative5-dev qt5-default qtbase5-private-dev`

HTH