# Installing ruby-qml - ERROR: Failed to build libqmlbind - What is missing?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, qml

I am trying to install [ruby-qml](https://github.com/seanchas116/ruby-qml) on Ubuntu 15.10 (Wily).

I had previously checked for prerequisites. There is nothing documented for Linux on the web site. I had checked some usual suspects (build-essential bison openssl libreadline5 libreadline-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev vim libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev git-core subversion autoconf xorg-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev). Checking/installing `libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5 qtdeclarative5-dev qt5-default` fixed some earlier problems.

At this point, when running the Gem installer, it stops with an error and the following output:

```
:#> gem install qml
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing qml:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby2.1 extconf.rb
checking for qmake... yes
  >>> building libqmlbind...
Project MESSAGE: This project is using private headers and will therefore be tied to this specific Qt module build version.
Project MESSAGE: Running this project against other versions of the Qt modules may crash at any arbitrary point.
Project MESSAGE: This is not a bug, but a result of using Qt internals. You have been warned!
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -std=c++0x -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQMLBIND_LIBRARY -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -Iinclude -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtQuick -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtQml -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtNetwork -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/5.4.2 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/5.4.2/QtCore -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -o api_application.o src/api_application.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -std=c++0x -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQMLBIND_LIBRARY -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -Iinclude -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtQuick -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtQml -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtNetwork -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/5.4.2 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/5.4.2/QtCore -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -o api_engine.o src/api_engine.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -std=c++0x -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQMLBIND_LIBRARY -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -Iinclude -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtQuick -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtQml -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtNetwork -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/5.4.2 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/5.4.2/QtCore -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -o api_iterator.o src/api_iterator.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -std=c++0x -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQMLBIND_LIBRARY -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -Iinclude -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtQuick -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtQml -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtNetwork -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/5.4.2 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/5.4.2/QtCore -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -o api_value.o src/api_value.cpp
In file included from src/metaobject.h:4:0,
                 from src/api_engine.cpp:3:
src/exporter.h:5:42: fatal error: private/qmetaobjectbuilder_p.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:446: recipe for target 'api_engine.o' failed
make: *** [api_engine.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
ERROR: Failed to build libqmlbind
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile  due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby2.1
        --with-qmake
        --without-qmake
        --enable-debug
        --disable-debug
        --enable-clean
        --disable-clean

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/qml-1.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/qml-1.0.2/gem_make.out
```

**What is wrong here? How can I fix it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed `qtbase5-private-dev`, and then:

```
Successfully installed qml-1.0.2
```